# SQL SERVER Find out non duplicate data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns as below

```
id   a   b
=================
1    1   2 
2    1   3
3    1   4
4    2   4
5    2   5
6    3   4
7    3   5
```

I wanna show the result

if a column or b column is duplicated,

I have try to use Group by ( a,b) but result is not I want.

I wanna Group by (a)  and show grouped first row A,B and B is not duplicated

In my example, A will grouped into { 1, 2 ,3 },

and B will show {2 , 4,  5} not {2,4,4}  because 4,4 is duplicated

```
id   a   b
=================
1    1   2 

4    2   4

7    3   5
```

How do I do for this ?

Sorry, I’m not good at English.

Thx for help.

Comment: Replicated?What is that?

Comment: I would have said to use `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` based on the description, but I don't see what the rules are for the relationship of your resoults to your base data.

Comment: duplicated ,sorry for my English

Answer (score 0):

This code goes from your example data to your example results. Seems strange though and I doubt this is what you're looking for. If you give more detail, then you can get a better answer.

```
CREATE TABLE Example
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    a INT NOT NULL,
    b INT NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT Example
VALUES
    (1, 1, 2) 
    , (2, 1, 3)
    , (3, 1, 4)
    , (4, 2, 3)
    , (5, 2, 4)
    , (6, 3, 4)

SELECT
    MIN(id) AS id
    , a
    , MIN(b) AS b
FROM
    Example
GROUP BY
    a

DROP TABLE Example
```